# Mocking a stored procedure with an output parameter

Tags: c#, moq

I am having following method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> PrintMasterBagAssignmentManifest(int companyId, int bagNo)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            if (companyId > 0 && bagNo > 0)
            {
                var companyNumber = companyId.ToString("D2");
                var bagNumber = bagNo.ToString("D8");

                DataParameter compParameter = new DataParameter("COMP", companyNumber);
                DataParameter bagParameter = new DataParameter("BAG", bagNumber);
                DataParameter userParameter = new DataParameter("USER", UserName);
                DataParameter statusOutputParameter = new DataParameter("STATUS", "");
                statusOutputParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                DataParameter[] param = new DataParameter[] {
                    compParameter,
                    bagParameter,
                    userParameter,
                    statusOutputParameter
                };

                MerretDataContext.ExecuteStoredProcedure("MBMANF", param);

                if (statusOutputParameter.Value.ToString() == "E" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(statusOutputParameter.Value.ToString()))
                {
                    errors.Add(string.Format(Resources.Resources.MASTERBAG_PRINTMANIFEST_ERROR, bagNo));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errors.Add(Resources.Resources.MASTERBAG_INVALID);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors.Add(ex.Message);
        }
        return errors;
    }
```

this method calls a stored procedure using LinqToDB and i am passing a parameter array which consists of 3 input parameters and one output parameter. i am having problem writing unit test for this. I am using MOQ framework.

Up on execution, this stored procedure stores either 'C' or 'E' into the output parameter 'statusOutputParameter'.

I have tried:

```
        const string RETURN_VALUE = "C";
        DataParameter[] dp = null;

        MockMerretDataContext.Setup(m => m.ExecuteStoredProcedure("MBLABL", It.IsAny<DataParameter[]>()))
            .Callback((string sp, DataParameter[] cdp) => 
            {
                dp = cdp;
                cdp[3].Value = RETURN_VALUE;
            });
```

the above unit test is getting passed but i am not sure how to return either C or E to 'statusOutputParameter' output parameter.

Comment: "I am having problem writing unit test for this".  Can you be more specific?  What have you tried, and what problem do you encounter trying it?

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your reply. I have updated with few more info. Please have a look.

Comment: Instead of executing it for any parameters, you can specify concrete values or execute logic inside your callback. Please specify use case, which you want to mock.

Comment: Hi KrzysztofUkl. After calling the stored procedure i want mock the 'IF' condition: if (statusOutputParameter.Value.ToString() == "E" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(statusOutputParameter.Value.ToString()))

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I was struggling with the same issue and found the solution.
Please try with a query parameter.

```
 const string RETURN_VALUE = "C";
        DataParameter[] dp = null;

        MockMerretDataContext.Setup(m => m.ExecuteStoredProcedure("MBLABL", It.IsAny<QueryParameter[]>()))
            .Callback((string sp, QueryParameter[] cdp) => 
            {
                // This returns the required value from @STATUS
                QueryParameter[] paramArrayTemp = (QueryParameter[])cdp;
                paramArrayTemp.Find<QueryParameter>(p => p.name == "@STATUS").value = RETURN_VALUE;
            });
```

Comment: It's how the Callback was constructed that helped me. Thanks!